# Creating Reports in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I have recently started working on a program that should not be changed much and there are problems that it closes properly with Robot Framework. The method that came to my mind now was that I could get the reports before the test end.

So I have this Question:

- Is there a possibility or keyword in Robotframework that I can use to get reports before the test is done?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i facing two Problem with our Programm. The first after the test end with RF the java process dont terminate and continue in the background.
 And the other one is, that when i quit our Programm with RF it also Terminate RF  without creating a report
So i thought i could create a Report and quit the Programm, before RF terminate

Comment: It sounds like you need to solve the problem of quitting your application, than the problem of generating reports before robot finishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a possibility or keyword in Robotframework that I can use to get reports before the test is done?

No, there is not. Robot creates the reports as an in-memory xml document. It doesn't write the data to disk until the tests are finished. It then runs a post-processing step to convert them to html.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bryan wrote, there is no way to get report.html during robot runtime as it is generated in postrun step.

However, you may use listener to get feedback from robot about execution status. For instance, in RED Robot Editor IDE, it is used to populate Execution View (see screenshot at the bottom):
http://nokia.github.io/RED/help/user_guide/launching/ui_elements.html

More about listener API: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/ExtendingRobotFramework/ListenerInterface.rst